# Согласование обобщающего слова и однородных членов

Tags: согласование

Как правильно?
Произведен осмотр с внешней и внутренней сторон изделия.
Произведен осмотр с внешней и внутренней стороны изделия.

Answer (score 1):

При одном существительном могут употребляться два определения, при этом определяемое существительное может быть как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа.

Думаю, здесь действует следующее правило:

Единственное число определяемого существительного употребляется  **для подчеркивания внутренней связи перечисляемых разновидностей предметов, обычно в сочетаниях терминологического характера** (головной и спинной мозг, глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида).

*Произведен осмотр с внешней и внутренней стороны изделия.*

Но если Вы хотите подчеркнуть, что именно с двух сторон, то лучше употребить множественное число:

Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа, если **подчеркивается наличие** нескольких предметов, например: золотая и серебряная медали; в западной и восточной частях страны.

*Произведен осмотр с внешней и внутренней сторон изделия.*